# I created a function using a for loop to display and add items to and from a dictionary. Does my code look good? Should I have done it differently?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, syntax

I am going through automate the boring stuff with python and I am currently learning about dictionaries. These functions deal with a basic inventory in a game.

My first function is to display the inventory and my second function is to update the inventory with the loot which is in a list.

Could you review my code? Is there anything that I should've coded differently or are there other best practices I should've followed?

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory: ')
    item_total = 0
    for k,v in inventory.items():
        item_total = item_total + v
        print(str(k) + ': ' + str(v))
    print('Total number of items: %d' %(item_total))

items = {
    'arrow' : 12,
    'gold coin' : 42,
    'rope' : 1,
    'torch' : 6,
    'dagger' : 1
    }

displayInventory(items)

dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems): 
    for x in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(x, 0)
        if x in inventory:
            inventory[x] += 1
    print(inventory)

addToInventory(items, dragonLoot)
```

Comment: you can use a `defaultdict` instead of setdefault call which is rather expensive (as the value to set is evaluated each time)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)